# /bin/sh: url: command not found

Tags: docker-compose, centos, dockerfile, centos7, yum

Running a `Dockerfile` containing

```
RUN yum install python3 -y\
    && url -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py \
    && python3 get-pip.py\
        #no --user - install for the whole machine
    && pip install awscli --upgrade
```

I get

```
/bin/sh: url: command not found
```

I clicked trough a lot of `/bin/sh: xyz: command not found` and didn't find more than I already knew: the package/executable `url` seems to be missing on my system. How do I install this on CentOS? A web search also yielded only useless results.

`yum install -y url` gives me `No package url available.`

Answer (score 2):

While the command `url -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` looks right on first sight, It contains a typo or copy-paste-mistake. `curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` with **curl** instead of **url** being correct.